# Kinect + Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create a standalone Kinect camera in a gazebo simulation (in electric) but am having trouble finding a simple tutorial that explains how to do so. I would like the entire model to be rendered as well. Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27704/kinect-+-gazebo/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good start is having a look at the [turtlebot_description](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_description) package, as this provides a simulated Kinect with only a little bit of overhead - the turtlebot ;) Getting rid of the robot model or copying only the relevant parts should be pretty straightforward.

An example launch file for launching the turtlebot in gazebo can be found in the [turtlebot_gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_gazebo) package and launched by executing

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo  turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

/Update:
The simulated kinect rgb image is then published on the "/camera/image_raw" topic and the point cloud is published on the "/camera/depth/points" topic. These topic names are set in the [turtlebot_description/urdf/gazebo.urdf.xacro](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/247a858a6a90/turtlebot_description/urdf/gazebo.urdf.xacro) xacro macro and can be changed when you setup your own simulated kinect. Note that the simulated Kinect currently does not provide RGB data for the point cloud.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2012-02-15**:
After running the above launch file, I can see the Kinect rendered in simulation; however, I do not see any of the Kinect's images being published after checking with rxgraph

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-02-15**:
Hi, see updated post above.

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2012-02-23**:
Hello, I have launched the turtlebot in gazebo but I do not see the PointCloud being published. I do, however see a laser scan being published. What do I need to do to get at a PointCloud?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-02-23**:
The laser scan normally is generated from the point cloud on the turtlebot using the pointcloud_to_laserscan node. So if there's a laser scan, there definitely should be a pointcloud published, too. You should probably open a new question with further information on the problem.

**Comment by [Yannis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2569/yannis/) on 2012-07-03**:
When trying to display the /camera/depth/points in Rviz, the only thing displayed is a flat PointCloud, approximately at 1meter from the robot. Any idea what would be the cause ? It is the same as pointed out on this issue: http://answers.ros.org/question/36801/flat-pointcloud-with-turtlebot-simulat